# compare two dataframes and display the data that are different

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark-pandas, pyspark-schema

i have two dataframes and i want to compare the values of two columns and display those who are different, for exemple: compare this Table 1

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| O1 | 2 | E1 | 2 |
| O1 | 3 | E1 | 1 |
| O1 | 2 | E1 | 0 |
| O1 | 5 | E2 | 2 |
| O1 | 2 | E2 | 3 |
| O1 | 2 | E2 | 2 |
| O1 | 5 | E2 | 1 |
| O2 | 8 | E1 | 2 |
| O2 | 8 | E1 | 0 |
| O2 | 0 | E1 | 1 |
| O2 | 2 | E1 | 4 |
| O2 | 9 | E1 | 2 |
| O2 | 2 | E2 | 1 |
| O2 | 9 | E2 | 4 |
| O2 | 2 | E2 | 2 |

with this table 2

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| O1 | 2 | E1 | 2 |
| O1 | 2 | E2 | 3 |
| O2 | 2 | E1 | 4 |
| O2 | 9 | E2 | 4 |

i tried

```
cond= [table1.A ==  table2.A, table1.C ==  table2.C, table1.D ==  table2.D]
join = table1.join(table2,cond,"leftsemi")
```

and since i have a lot of data in it, i don't know how to check if the result i've got is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your dataframes has the same schema, you can use `subtract`

###### `df1`

```py
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 2, 3, 4),
    (5, 6, 7, 8),
], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|  4|
|  5|  6|  7|  8|
+---+---+---+---+
```

###### `df2`

```py
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([
    (5, 6, 7, 8),
], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|
+---+---+---+---+
|  5|  6|  7|  8|
+---+---+---+---+
```

###### `subtract` to get data that exists in `df1` but does not exists in `df2`

```py
df1.subtract(df2).show()

+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|  4|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Feel free to accept it as an answer if it answer your question, or upvote it if you found it helpful

Comment: thank you, it did answer my question ^^ and unfortunatly i can't upvote it; i need 15 reputations to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of tuple from one dataframe

`check_list = list(df2.apply(tuple, axis=1))`

and use it to compare with other

`df1 =df1[~df1.apply(tuple, axis=1).isin(check_list)]`

Comment: when i try this solution i've got this error

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'apply'